# Perform an action on Knocking on the phone when the device is asleep?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, swift, android-ble

Im trying to implement a feature that I've seen an few apps, I think for both Android and iOS.. They are calling a function to perform on double knock (tap on the phone) when the app is close and or the screen is locked.. the exact action they were doing is to talk to a BLE device and turn it on/off by knocking on the phone when it is in their pocket.. any idea on how they are doing that?

Im working on Android part of this project. iOS is also having the same issue figuring out the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly follow the Following link, it may helpful.

https://www.android-examples.com/detect-double-tap-click-on-screen-in-android-programmatically/